# play mp3 file from raw folder in my android app

Tags: android, mp3

hi i have the code whish get list mp3 file from sdcard in my phone ,
how i can change it to get mp3  from raw folder

```
public ArrayList<Track> getTracksOnMDS() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver
            .query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    return convertMediaStoreCursorToArrayList(cursor);
}
```

i replace some code to do this but it is not work

```
File ring = new File("android.resource://com.bk.lrandom/res/raw/_10.mp3");
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ring.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I don't see any code that actually plays the audio file.

Comment: yes there is not any code to play mp3 file

Comment: Raw resources are not files at runtime, so you can't get a File object for them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code snippet to play audio file from raw folder

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
mPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg_music);
mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks it was a mistake :) . Actually those permission was the part of another answer :p